# Health check properties for springboot application in PCF

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, cloud-foundry, pcf, pivotal-web-services

I have configured the below health check properties in my spring boot application(using actuator) and returning "UP" when locally tested using the below endpoint

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /account/v1
  port: 8443
  
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      path-mapping:
        health: /health
```

Check locally using "http://localhost:8443/account/v1/actuator/health and returning
{"status":"UP"}"

In PCF I updated the Health check type as **"http"** and Endpoint as **"/actuator/health"**.
When I pushed my app I am getting the below error

```
2020-09-02T12:43:15.92+0530 [HEALTH/0] ERR Failed to make HTTP request to '/actuator/health' on port 8080: connection refused
   2020-09-02T12:43:15.92+0530 [CELL/0] ERR Failed after 1m0.632s: readiness health check never passed.
```

Please help on this.(Is my port or endpoint wrong)

Comment: Have you tried using `/account/v1/actuator/health` like you are locally? You have the context path, but that would be required in the URL as well. Also, are you using a route path with your application in CF?

Comment: Tried using /account/v1/actuator/health. But not working

Comment: This link might help: https://docs.run.pivotal.io/console/using-actuators.html  Also your port says 8443 but your error log says port as 8080.

Comment: Look for these two lines in the log output as your app starts: 1.) `o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 19 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'` and 2.) `o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''`. These will tell you the port, context path and base path for actuators. You should be able to assemble those to figure out the health check link.

Answer (score 1):

As per the logs, Readiness check is failed.

> **Readiness check**: it occurs at 60 seconds by default during app start, the client (healthcheck app) connects to the app listening port
> and waits up to 1 second.

Looks like the server takes longer than 60 secs. Increase the timeout and check (Default is 60s, You can increase the value up to 180s)

Timeout can be added in the application manifest file. For Eg:

> **timeout: 180**
> health-check-type: http
> health-check-http-endpoint: /health